# Loading binary file on VUEJS with jBinary

Tags: javascript, parsing, vue.js

I'm trying to load a binary file et read the content 
For this, i'm using the load function to get my binary file and then, 
I call a function that parse the binary file. 

The problem is , I can access the datas 
 
I keep havin this error :

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'parsePeturboDATFiles' of undefined
>       at eval (eval at 79 (0.05b4762….hot-update.js:7), :128:11)

I did try to console.log my data to see what is going wrong, but I can print my data but I can't pass it to my other parsing functions ... I cannot figure why.

Here's my code by the way :

```
<template>
  <div class="cde">
    <h1></h1>
  </div>
</template>



<script>
  import jbinary from 'jbinary'
  export default {
    name: 'CDE',
    data () {
      return {
      }
    },
    methods : {
      parsePeturboDATFiles : function (data) {
        console.log(data)


      },
    },
    mounted : function () {
      jbinary.load('./static/test.dat').then(function (data) {
        console.log(data.view) //works fine
        this.parsePeturboDATFiles(data.view) //get an error

      })

    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that it's not able to read the `parsePeturboDATFiles` property because the `this` variable is evaluating to `undefined`. Store a reference to `this` in another variable `self` and then use that to call `parsePeturboDATFiles()`:

```
mounted : function () {
  var self = this;
  jbinary.load('./static/test.dat').then(function (data) {
    self.parsePeturboDATFiles(data.view);
  })
}
```